# Initialize Google Protobuf RepeatedField collections

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

When you try to initialize a repeated field member (property) of already generated Google Protobuf message type, you can't use a setter since they are read-only.

How to initialize google Protobuf message's RepeatedField collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collection property/member generated from `repeated` on `.proto` files are read-only. They get initialized as soon as you new up an instance of your generated protobuf type. Since it is a read-only collection, you can't set it to another instance but you could add elements to already created instance.

You need to use Google Protobuf .net library's extension methods (for me which was not intuitive since at the time of writing this article I wasn't getting IntelliSense support in VS 2019) for doing so.

For example, if your protobuf generated type is `Price` which happens to have a repeated field/collection Promotion like `repeated Promotion promotions = <some int>` then you'd do

```
var price = new Price(); //just placeholder for already generated message
//other code
var promotions = new List<Promotion>(); //List is just an example
//code to populate promotions 
price.Promotions.Add(promotions);
```

Official reference [link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-#public-functions)

Comment: Get-only collection properties that you can modify is pretty common over a wide range of libraries and APIs, FWIW. As a side note: different library (same serialization format), but: protobuf-net allows you to use either approach.

Comment: @sbp answer shows how you **can** use an initializer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615615/459102)

Comment: Hey @AaronHudon, the issue I had was for already generated proto message (which is being passed around through some builders) ; The linked answer in your comment is only applicable if you are also newing up proto right before adding values to repeated field collection. I've replaced 'a' with 'already' in my question to emphasis this issue.

Answer (score 24):

Although it's a bit weird syntax, you can actually use a collection *inside* a collection initializer on a `RepeatedField` like this:

```
var promotions = new List<Promotion>(); 
// code to populate promotions 
var price = new Price() { Promotions = { promotions } };
```

This works because `RepeatedField` defines a custom collection initializer (overload for `Add` that takes `IEnumerable<T>`).

I guess this was a workaround so these fields could be declared `readonly` within messages, but still work with collection initializers.

Comment: Works with a LINQ query inside that inner `{ }` initializer too.

Comment: @Peter Wishart, Thank you for "This works because..." explanation.

Comment: This initialization method is especially convenient when you initialize a large structure with multiple repeated fields. Adding a list to the repeated field on a separate call, as in the accepted answer, works too, but the code is more verbose.